# How to get the area under the curve from multivariate analysis

Tags: classification, multivariate-analysis

I have two groups, A and B. They have a number of variables as follows

```
  Group, Age, Sex, NumberofSomething, NumberofSomething2
```

I want to determine which of the variables and combination of variables best predicts membership of a group. I then want to calculate an area under the ROC curve for this.

My question is:
Does the multivariate analysis also tell me the best combination of factors (is this done by linear discriminant analysis in my case?), and also, how do I then use the results of the multivariate analysis to generate the area under the ROC curve?

Comment: "Multivariate" means multiple response variables while "multivariable" indicates multiple predictors. Do you have multiple groups which people are members of?

Comment: I have two groups only

Comment: Can people be a member of neither group?

Comment: No. You are either one or the other